# Jetty WebSocketException: RemoteEndpoint unavailable

Tags: java, jetty, java-websocket

I have 2 Threads in my application - server (main) and service, which inform user about coordinate changes.
So when the page is reloaded I have error:

```
Exception in thread "Timer-1" org.eclipse.jetty.websocket.api.WebSocketException: RemoteEndpoint unavailable, current state [CLOSING], expecting [OPEN or CONNECTED]
at org.eclipse.jetty.websocket.common.WebSocketSession.getRemote(WebSocketSession.java:252)
at service.MyService.run(MyService.java:67)
at java.util.TimerThread.mainLoop(Timer.java:555)
at java.util.TimerThread.run(Timer.java:505)
```

and thread closed.

How to solve it?